# Is the following method of determining a curve from its normal vector valid?

Tags: differential-geometry

One of my homework problems asks us to show that the curvature and the torsion of a regular parameterised curve with non-zero torsion everywhere are uniquely determined, when we already have the knowledge of its normal vector function. This in term is equivalent to determine a curve from a given normal vector function $n(s)$, by use of the fundamental theorem of the local theory of curves.

> Attempt:
>   From the Frenet formulas we conclude that
>   $-\langle n',b\rangle n=b'$.
>   This is a first-order differential equation, which hence must possess a unique solution. Could one conclude from here that the normal function can uniquely determine the binormal vector, hence the torsion, hence the curvature of a curve?

Inform me of any error that occurs, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use `\langle` and `\rangle` for the angle brackets $\langle\rangle$. $<$ and $>$ are for inequalities. (@martini and I made identical edits to your posts fixing this, 3 seconds apart.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, thanks for the information.